# Interaction between radio and select in jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I have the following problem: I have a select-box with e.g. 3 values, a radio-button group and a checkbox.

My intention is to check and disable the checkbox in case of the third value in the selectbox is selected or the certain (second) radio-button is checked.

the problem is: whenever I select the other radiobutton, the checkbox is checked but not disabled, even though the selectbox is selected with the third value. Or if I change the value of the selectbox, the checkbox is enabled, even though the certain radiobutton is selected.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

```
<select id="sel" >
<option id="opt1" value="0"></option>
<option id="opt1"  value="1" >nope</option>
<option id="opt2"  value="2" >nope</option>
<option id="opt2"  value="3" >this</option>
</select>


<input type="radio" name="11" value="first" id="one"></input>
<input type="radio" name="11" value="second" id="two" ></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="22" value="third" id="third" ></input>


$("input[name='11']").change(function(){
if($("#one").is(":checked")) {
    $("#third").prop("checked",true).prop("disabled","disabled");
} else {   
    $("#third").attr("disabled", false);
}  
});

$("#sel").change(function(){
var m = $("#sel").val();
if (m == "3") {
    $("#third").attr("checked",true).attr("disabled","disabled");
} else {    
    $("#third").attr("disabled", false);}  
});
```

here the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/gcxbgdhc/2/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a separate function that checks whether to make the checkbox selected and/or disabled or not and calling that function on the change events of the radio buttons and the select, like so:

```
$("input[name='11']").change(function(){
    setCheckbox();
});

$("#sel").change(function(){
    setCheckbox();
});

var setCheckbox = function() {
    if ($('#sel').val() === '3' || $('#two').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#third').click().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#third').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
};
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gcxbgdhc/5/)

Edit:

Just add an if statement.  I should probably point out that if you have any further specifications you need, there are probably some very simple if statements that will fix the problem.

So in this example, change

```
$('#third').click().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to

```
if (!$('#third').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#third').click();
    }
$('#third').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

And I've updated the fiddle.  Cheers!

Comment: first of all thank you for the idea with the seperate function. . The problem here is, the checkbox must be checkable, even if the val() is not '3' or the radiobutton (in your case "bad") is not checked. In your Demo, if i check the checkbox first and after that select the val()===3 or check the radiobutton "bad", it unchecks the checkbox and disable it. Hope you see what I mean

Comment: Easy fix.  I've added an "Edit" section to the post.